# Fairly large (20 MB) data from nodejs to frontend using https

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3

I have a process running which pushing some data into s3 and on request from user I want to read from s3 and serve that to user, but every s3 file is about 20 MB data which is not a good idea serving 20 mb data to user on every request, Is there any other method to do this?

I understand I can use PIPE to stream the data, but is there any other method?

Comment: Seems like you're not telling the whole story.  If the appropriate response for a request is 20 MB then that seems fine.  Just let caching do its thing.  But when you say _"on every request"_, it seems like you're alluding to some kind of data-specific optimization, like maybe there's some redundancy in the responses or something.  Can you give more details?

Comment: If you need to send the user a file from S3, why not just redirect them so they download it directly from S3?

Comment: @Wyck so basically I am generating 500 graph (heatmap) data by some calculation on crypto trade data on every minute, and saving the generated graph data into s3 because it is cheap (I could have used kafka/redis to serve data immediately when user connects to a channel, did not used due to heavy load of data). So I am thinking serving the graph data from s3 whenever user requests for the graph data.

Comment: @AnonCoward I cannot make the bucket public. I want to first process the coming request (may be auth) and then serve the data.

Comment: I didn't suggest to make the bucket public.  You can redirect with a pre signed URL